# 2008 Group Policy Manager not propagating registry preferences into windows server 2003 boxes

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have a Windows 2008r2 Domain with 2008r2/2012 Group Policy Manager.
In my domain, I still have windows server 2003 boxes (about 50 of them)

I'm trying to push registry updates via Preferences\Windows Settings\Registry.
While they show perfectly, I'm getting a 'N/A' in the gpresult registry settings in the boxes.
Other GPO line items propogate perfectly.

There's no errors in the 2003 servers.  It's as if the GPO decides not to push registry settings.

Of note, I also attempted to add a startup bat script, and that's not getting propogated either.

Where can I go and dig out why the registry settings are not being pushed out to my servers?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the Group Policy Preference Client Side Extensions. (It's a download for xp, 2003, 2003 r2)

GPP was introduced in 2008, thus any OS below need the extension installed to be abl;e to process them.

> Multiple Group Policy Preferences have been added to the Windows
>   Server 2008 Group Policy Management Console (which are also available
>   through the Remote Server Administration Toolset (RSAT) for Windows
>   Vista SP1). Group Policy Preferences enable information technology
>   professionals to configure, deploy, and manage operating system and
>   application settings they previously were not able to manage using
>   Group Policy. **After you install this update, your computer will be
>   able to process the new Group Policy Preference extensions.** After you
>   install this item, you may have to restart your computer.

From [Group Policy Preference Client Side Extensions for Windows Server 2003 (KB943729)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=6955)